# Returning ROWID instead of a value in a multi join query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am interested in returning the ROWID of a LEFT JOIN table and I am not sure how to structure the SELECT for this. The LEFT JOIN table has string values and no primary key.

For example: TableA has a StringValue FK into TableB

TableA (PK,StringValue)

TableB (StringValue)

```
SELECT TableA.PK AS ID, **ROWID TableB??**
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.StringValues = TableA.StringValues;
```

I tried multiple ways to call ROWID but nothing was returned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using something like this :

```
SELECT a.PK AS ID, b.rowid
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.StringValue = a.StringValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use to get one ID in another form that I need for the calling form. Sorry I do not use join but once you have both ID's can you then join
The calling value is udID the return value is newData
public void GetID(int udID)
{
newData = udID;
return;
}